# Cookie not being sent with Fetch API CORS request even with credentials set to "include"

Tags: javascript, rest, cookies, fetch-api

This is a very interesting and weird problem.

We're having a university project and one part is to create a Javascript client that sends requests to a REST API hosted on a Docker container on port 8000. In this project, cookies are also very important and are used to check login sessions and whether a user is authorized to do certain requests.

The problem I have is that using Fetch, even with *credentials* set to *"include"*, Fetch will not send the current session cookie in the HTTP request header.

Here's the code for the POST event handler

```
    else if(event.target && event.target.id == "create") {
            event.preventDefault();
    
            //getting text
            const poem = document.querySelector("#create-poem").elements.dikttekst.value;
            
            //checking if poem is empty
            if(poem == "")
                statusField.innerHTML = `${DEFAULT_DEBUG_TEXT} Poem is empty!`;
        
            else {
                const url = "http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/rest.py/poembase/poem/"
        
                const data = `${poem}`;
    
                const cookie_data = document.cookie;
                
                //fetch
                fetch(url, {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/xml",
                        "Accept": "application/xml"
                    },
                    credentials: "include",
                    body: data
    
                })
                .then(response => response.text())
                .catch(error => alert(error))
                .then(data => statusField.innerHTML = `${DEFAULT_DEBUG_TEXT}${data}`);
            }
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    
        }
```

Yes, I have configured the backend Access-Control

```
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Accept"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
```

I have tried to set the SameSite attribute of the cookie to "" so that it is atleast not Strict. Though I don't think this should affect anything as the request is done through the same site. Regardless, it did nothing no matter what I set it to.

And yes, I have checked out all relevant answer on StackOverflow. The closest thing to an answer was that *cookies are only being sent if the client's port is the same as the server's*, but here's the kicker: **this all worked perfectly fine on my part a few hours ago!**

It's a long story, but it goes like this:

Initially, I had the same problem as I had now, but for some reason, after moving the POST event handler to a different event handler, **BOOM** suddenly it works perfectly fine.
I was actually getting ready to push it to GitHub, and decided to edit some code completely unrelated to the JavaScript code, and then when I saved that and decided to test again, it suddenly doesn't work anymore.

And even more bizarre, this works on my class mates system! For him, he manages to send the cookie with the request. He just pulled from the repository and his backend config is virtually the same. I copied his backend headers but to no avail, still won't send any cookie.

We are considering just accepting it as it is practically working fine on my mate's system, but I'd really like to know what is wrong.

So I am all out of answers and have no idea why this is happening. There's no consistency in this at all.

## TLDR Cookies were sent earlier on my system but not anymore. It also works on my mate's system despite him only pulling from the GitHub branch

Answer (score 0):

nevermind....I thought I had it solved but surprise, after some changes to the JS file to add comments and removing unnecessary variables, it's back again, even when trying to revert the JS file back to when I know it worked...